# Silverlight template selector solution works great, but not blend able

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datatemplate, selector, blend

Before I begin here is a reference to how I implemented a template selector with Silverlight.

http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx

Everything works great.  But the solution just doesn't work in blends making things more difficult to visualize overall.  Is the correct work flow to just create a UserControl from the contents and embed it inside the Resource Dictionary to make it blendable, or is there a better way to do this?

Either way, I'm asking this question and posting the Template Selector solution at the same time, because I found it useful.  Better solutions are very much welcome.

fyi.. sl4,.net4, latest blends.. all the new toys.. using mvvm light(little relevance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you go with the the following kind of implementation: [DataTemplateSelector on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector).

The drawback of the link you posted is that the location and name of the templates are hard-coded in the ContentControl's implementation. With the approach provided in the article I link to, the data templates are accessed in-line, or by regular {StaticResource} references (which means more flexibility), and on top of that, Blend knows what to do with that.